# Why facebook permission is deleted, the status is still connected?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use this to get user's permission

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '00000000000000000000000',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function login()
{

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) 
        {

        } else
        {
            console.log('Authorization failed.');
        }
    },{scope: 'user_posts,manage_pages,publish_pages,publish_actions'});
}
```

And this use this to delete the permission

```
function disconnect()
{
    FB.api('me/permissions',
            'DELETE',
            function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) 
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Authorization failed.');
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Now I use this to check authorization

```
function getLoginStatus()
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
}
```

But the status still connected, and the access token still exists. I must refresh the browser to get correct status.

I cannot recognize status if API does not return me correct status. How to make sure I can get correct status without browser refresh?

Comment: What is the actual response?

Comment: actual response is `Object {status: "connected", authResponse: Object}authResponse: ObjectaccessToken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"expiresIn: 7194signedRequest: "xxxxxxxxxx"userID: "xxxxxx"__proto__: Objectstatus: "connected"__proto__: Object`, correct response should be `Object {authResponse: undefined, status: "not_authorized"}`

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue to me. I know that the SDK caches things, so maybe it's just that you're not seeing changes because it's still using the cached version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object is cached by the SDK. Try passing with the second parameter:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, true);
```